# Shifting Null Values From MySQL Result Set

Tags: mysql, join

I have this query:

```
SELECT p.status, s.name AS "Senior", j.name AS "Junior", sp.name AS "Sophomore", f.name AS "Freshman"
FROM matrix p
LEFT JOIN senior s ON p.id = s.id
LEFT JOIN junior j ON p.id = j.id
LEFT JOIN sophomore sp ON p.id = sp.id
LEFT JOIN freshman f ON p.id = f.id
ORDER BY f.name, sp.name, j.name, s.name DESC
```

Which returns this result:

```
| Senior | Junior | Sohpomore | Freshman |
------------------------------------------
| Value  | NULL   | NULL      | NULL     |
| Value  | NULL   | NULL      | NULL     |
| Value  | NULL   | NULL      | NULL     |
| NULL   | Value  | NULL      | NULL     |
| NULL   | Value  | NULL      | NULL     |
| NULL   | Value  | NULL      | NULL     |
| NULL   | NULL   | Value     | NULL     |
| NULL   | NULL   | Value     | NULL     |
| NULL   | NULL   | Value     | NULL     |
| NULL   | NULL   | NULL      | Value    |
| NULL   | NULL   | NULL      | Value    |
| NULL   | NULL   | NULL      | Value    |
```

My question, is it possible to shift the second, third, and fourth columns' values up so that they all line up (and all the null values show up at the bottom)? Thanks in advance for your help.

By the way, I'm retrieving the values with PHP, in case that helps.

**Update**: Status is not unique. It can only be 2 values, which I'm not displaying to the user. Also, just to make my question a little clearer, this is the result I'm trying to accomplish:

```
| Senior | Junior | Sohpomore | Freshman |
------------------------------------------
| Value  | Value  | Value     | Value    |
| Value  | Value  | Value     | Value    |
| Value  | Value  | Value     | Value    |
| NULL   | Value  | NULL      | Value    |
| NULL   | Null   | NULL      | Value    |
| NULL   | Null   | NULL      | NULL     |
```

**Update 2** Here's the structure for all tables:

```
Matrix: ID, Status, Student Name, Major, Class Standing
Senior: ID, Name
Junior: ID, Name
Sophomore: ID, Name
Freshman: ID, Name
```

Comment: Please show sample data for `matrix` and the other tables.

Comment: Updated with the table structures.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with aggregation:

```
SELECT p.status, max(s.name) AS "Senior", max(j.name) AS "Junior",
       max(sp.name) AS "Sophomore", max(f.name) AS "Freshman"
FROM matrix p
LEFT JOIN senior s ON p.id = s.id
LEFT JOIN junior j ON p.id = j.id
LEFT JOIN sophomore sp ON p.id = sp.id
LEFT JOIN freshman f ON p.id = f.id
GROUP BY p.status
ORDER BY f.name, sp.name, j.name, s.name DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment, so I'll ask here;  what are you trying to have each row represent?  There's a 'status' field -- is this unique to each class table?  i.e. if there's a status of "A", is there one and only one freshman, sophomore, junior and senior that correspond to that status?

I need to know more about the data you're working with and what you're trying to accomplish before I (or anyone) can provide any kind of solution.

EDIT:  Here's what I think is most likely your best bet (I can't test it right now, so apologies if I've missed a syntax error).  It will give you a long, narrow list of students with a "class" field that you can use to differentiate them in your CSS:

```
SELECT
    p.status,
    "senior" AS class,
    s.name
FROM
    matrix AS p
    JOIN senior AS s 
        ON p.id = s.id
UNION
SELECT
    p.status,
    "junior" AS class,
    j.name
FROM
    matrix AS p
    JOIN junior AS j
        ON p.id = j.id
UNION
SELECT
    p.status,
    "sophomore" AS class,
    sp.name
FROM
    matrix AS p
    JOIN sophomore AS sp
        ON p.id = sp.id
UNION
SELECT
    p.status,
    "freshman" AS class,
    f.name
FROM
    matrix AS p
    JOIN freshman AS f
        ON p.id = f.id;
```

Comment: Status is not unique (essentially, it's enrolled or not enrolled), and is inconsequential to what is displayed. I'm only selecting it so I can change CSS depending on what value each row has.

Comment: @misdreavus79 Okay I think I see what's up here.  You're thinking of the output vertically, like an Excel spreadsheet.  MySQL doesn't really work that way, each row needs to represent /something/.  In your code, there's no relationship between Senior, Junior, Sophomore, etc -- that's fine for Excel, but in MySQl there needs to be a relationship between those fields.  I'll update my answer with a possible solution

Comment: Oh don't worry about it, I shifted the cells in PHP. I just wanted to know if there was a straightforward way to do this in SQL.

Comment: @misdreavus79 Yeah there's no way, not without doing something crazy slash stupid.  In MySQL there isn't such a thing as a 'cell', not in the Excel sense.